# Browsers and SSLv3 End-of-Life

Tags: tls, web-browser

Is there a point in time at which browsers will refuse to connect to web servers that support SSLv3 in addition to TLS 1.0/1.1/1.2? Will they produce warnings?

I assume the browser would be content using TLS 1.2 but am concerned that leaving SSLv3 (for the time being) might cause a poor user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers will use the highest supported protocol negotiated between it and the server, even if SSLv3 is enabled.

Newer browsers have SSL disabled, so will not be vulnerable to downgrade attacks.

Also see here [TLS/SSL support history of web browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:TLS/SSL_support_history_of_web_browsers).